# Seeking alternative to Google Maps Elevation API

Tags: data, software-recommendations, elevation, license

The [Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start) lets me pass a URL like

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.984703
```

along with a developer key, and get a result like

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.73915360,
            "lng" : -104.98470340
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

My company want to use something like this, but don't have the time for their legal department to go through the license.

Is there something similar with an MIT, Apache, GPL2, or similar license?

Basically, we want to input lat/long and get back elevation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the Open-Elevation API (https://open-elevation.com/) that looks promising

see
https://github.com/Jorl17/open-elevation/blob/master/docs/api.md
for API examples

Live API sample:
https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?locations=41.161758,-8.583933

Answer (score 15):

I've been working on [opentopodata.org](https://www.opentopodata.org/) as a free, open alternative to the Google Maps Elevation API.

Request URLs look like this:

https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/eudem25m?locations=51.875127,-3.341298

and the response is similar to Google Maps:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "elevation": 502.43035888671875, 
      "location": {
        "lat": 51.875127, 
        "lng": -3.341298
      }
    }
  ], 
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Open Topo Data is [MIT licensed](https://github.com/ajnisbet/opentopodata/). You can host it yourself or use the free public API.

The public API has a number of open DEM datasets loaded, including a 30m global dataset, the 25m EU-DEM dataset for Europe, and the 10m NED dataset for the US.

Answer (score -1):

[Clockwork Micro](https://www.clockworkmicro.com/services/elevation-api) offers an elevation API that uses the 1/3 arc-second dataset provided by the USGS. The coverage is all of the US.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".