# Open-Elevation API Accuracy

Tags: elevation, google-elevation-api

How accurate is the [Open-Elevation API](https://open-elevation.com/)?

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://www.geodose.com/2018/03/create-elevation-profile-generator-python.html) (except with `s=1000` to get high-accuracy data), and get the following elevation profile:

[image: desc]

However, using Google Earth Pro, I get a much finer elevation profile (the accuracy of the start and end points appear OK):

[image: desc]

Do we know why that is? Does Google use a different dataset, or does it essentially apply some interpolation to the results I get with the `open-elevation` API? The location is Greece in case that matters.

I'm also unable to set `s=2000` or higher for some reason, so I can't increase the resolution more apparently:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Radio Astronomy/linkCoverage/example_elevation.py", line 64, in <module>
    fp=urllib.request.urlopen(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you cribbed from claims that OpenElevation API uses 1 arc-second SRTM data (about 30M spacing), which should give a result much closer to what you are seeing from Google. However, a comment to this answer on [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/325305/4449) says that the host-your-own package provides a script to load 250M data, which would give a result more like what you're seeing. Perhaps that's what the public API is providing as well.

[OpenTopoData.org](https://www.opentopodata.org/) has a very similar interface, though it does limit you to 100 points per call, 1 call per second, 1000 calls per day. They have 30M or better resolution world-wide.

Comment: When you say "give a result much closer to what you are seeing from Google", do you mean the SRTM dataset is coarser/finer than Google's, or something else? I'm guessing OpenElevation (whether via the Public API or self-hosted) cannot give me much finer results.

I'll look into OpenTopoData in the hopes of getting more accurate elevation profiles, cheers!